# Azure container instance behave differently that local container

Tags: azure-container-service

I have a strange situation that i would like to share with you.
I started container recently and wand to have Azure DevOps agent running on container.

- On my windows 10 laptop , i can instanciate a Linux container and
  everything run & execute well (using WSL)
- On a Ubuntu VM running an Azure, the same container run well and
  execute well
- However the same container in Azure Container instance failed and for unknow reason i get the following error:

> - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
>   /bin/sh: 1: wslpath: not found
>   01 12 2022 14:55:59.933:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
>   Error: Command failed: wslpath -w "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin"
>   /bin/sh: 1: wslpath: not found

When i see **wsl** i think about Windows Subsystem Linux but i am not sure. I really do not understand why ACI behave like that with that error.
I always thought that container should behave the same wherever it runs. Did you experience it ? Any idea are welcome.
Regards

Comment: Let me see if I understand, the container is devoid of a custom application that was build using a framework like angular, react or ..., the dockerfile may just have a FROM and COPY tags? Is that correct?

Comment: Hi MZM, Basically the container is taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops. It consists to connect to an Azure Devops instance. At this stage the agent is well registered wherever it run (in mu local laptop, on VM Ubuntu, on ACI). Then the container build a solution and run 'npm task unit test'. It works well on my local laptop and VM Ubuntu. But same container on ACI failed. Thx a lot for your opinion

Comment: You're thoughts are generally correct, about container running on any docker hosted machine, but the Microsoft document (Learn link provided), states the following,  "Tasks and scripts might depend on specific tools being available on the container's PATH, and it's your responsibility to ensure that these tools are available." Thk for the question.

Comment: You give me good idea about the container's PATH. I suppose that you are talking command like printenv, set, echo $PATH. I will compare what i have in my container running with ACI versus container running with Ubuntu VM. If you have any other i idea i wil take